# Unsubscribe behavior (marketing Cloud Connect)

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I'll try my best to phrase my question -
We are sending emails from within Marketing Cloud to the leads and contacts in Salesforce.

These are basically triggered sends and used for commercial sends. Sents are happening to a single subscriber at a time (based on some events)

Now, if the subscriber unsubscribes, will it be a Master unsubscribe? and What will happen to that contact in Salesforce?

I know the unsubscribe behavior for list and Data Extension sends. What will happen in case of a Triggered Send to a single subscriber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a triggered send to lead with ID 00Q6F0000138N67

When the send is done it looked up in All Subscriber List, and if no subscriber key exist for above, it created a new one with 
00Q6F0000138N67UAE.

Now when I clicked on Unsubscribe From All(in the email I received), it got unsubscribed from all subscriber list. In Salesforce there is a field called EmailOptOut, this got ticked when the unsubscribe is processed.